# IE8 Will Not Install SSL Certificate

Tags: internet-explorer-8, ssl-certificate

I have my own SSL for development purposes. Normally when IE would give you the WARNING you could simply install the certificate, resart IE and go back to the server without warning. In IE8 I cannot avoid the warning. I have installed the certificate into every single store without success using both the MMC and cert manager in IE8. WHAT AM I MISSING?!

Comment: I gave up with IE8 and used Firefox which does allow you to install your own self signed certificate.

Answer (score 3):

Add the site to trusted sites. Then you will have the option to install the certificate after clicking the Certificate error box and then View Certificate.

Comment: Thanks. FYI in IE 8 there's no longer a certificate box, it's in the address bar to the right of the URL.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work either. After installing the certificate IE still shows the "Certificate Error: Navigation Blocked" page.

Answer (score 1):

Which certificate are you trying to install?

You must install the ROOT certificate, not the END-ENTITY certificate which is signed by that self-signed root.  It should go in the Trusted Root Certification authorities store.

Comment: Could you give more detailed info about how to do this in IE8? I've tried installing the ROOT certificate into the Trusted Root Certification  and I still get the "Certificate Error: Navigation Blocked" page.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure your **cert's CommonName matches the domain name**. For example, if you website will be accessed at 'https://www.example.com', CommonName should be 'www.example.com'. If this doesn't match, nothing you do in the second and third step will matter.
2. Run IE8 in **administrator** mode and navigate to your HTTPS URL. Continue beyond warning, then view the site's cert to access the 'Install Certificate' button.
3. Add the cert to **Trusted Root CA Certificates**.
4. Restart IE8 in protected mode then navigate to your HTTPS URL again. All warnings should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

I could not install the certificate from IE. I had to finally use MMC (Management Console). Instructions here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757688(v=ws.10).aspx