# SSL Certificate error with IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, ssl, openssl

It's a duplicate question:

[What do I need to do to get Internet Explorer 8 to accept a self signed certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681695/what-do-i-need-to-do-to-get-internet-explorer-8-to-accept-a-self-signed-certific)

[IE8 Will Not Install SSL Certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042035/ie8-will-not-install-ssl-certificate)

But, I'm asking same question again because it's not answered in that thread. except that OP'd to change his browser from IE to Firefox.

I've installed the certificate under **Trusted Root Certification Authorities.**
And, following are the details about certificate.

[image]

[image]

So, my question is **"Does any solution exist for IE8?"**

Comment: welcome to IE nightmare.

Comment: But I see other `https` sites opened without error. So, what am i missing?

Comment: This certificate is your certificate and is `self signed`?

Comment: @memosdp: Yes, by using `openssl`

Comment: I'm asking this because, even if this certificate is `self signed` it has to have some important sections to be accepted from IE. I know this is weird but this is the `IE nightmare` as @ShivanRaptor said. I don't know these sections to help you but maybe someone will know or maybe google will help you better on this.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/681695/what-do-i-need-to-do-to-get-internet-explorer-8-to-accept-a-self-signed-certific

Comment: @ShivanRaptor: better link, will add to question.